# How best to implement viewmodel with SwipeRefresh

Tags: android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating my model with modelview and services. This is the best way to create with swipeRefresh
I don't know if I'm doing it the right way so I'm asking for your help
who can give feedback thank you very much.
In fact everything is working perfectly I'm just in doubt about this part:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
         val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()
```

my method SwipeRefresh:

```
@Composable
    fun SwipeRefresh( content: @Composable (lists:ArrayList<ShoppingCart>) -> Unit){
        val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
        val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()

        com.google.accompanist.swiperefresh.SwipeRefresh(
                state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing),
                onRefresh = { viewModel.refresh() },
                indicator = { state, trigger ->
                    SwipeRefreshIndicator(
                            // Pass the SwipeRefreshState + trigger through
                            state = state,
                            refreshTriggerDistance = trigger,
                            // Enable the scale animation
                            scale = true,
                            // Change the color and shape
                            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
                    )
                }

        ) {

            if(isRefreshing){
                if(tipos=="frutas"){
                    tipos = "fruta"
                }

                frutas.tipo=tipos
                frutas.getFrutas()

               when(tipos){
                    "saladas"->{
                        val s by frutas.saladasData.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
                        list = ArrayList(s)
                    }
                    "fruta"->{
                        val f by frutas.frutaData.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
                        list = ArrayList(f)
                    }
                    "temperos"->{
                        val t by frutas.temperosData.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
                        list = ArrayList(t)
                    }
                }

            }
                Log.i("LIST",list.toString())
                val t = list.filter { it.product_title!="" }

                if(list.isNotEmpty() && t.isNotEmpty()){
                    content(list)
                }else{
                    helpers.loadingComponent()
                }

            }
        }
```

My ViewModel:

```
package com.example.quitanda.models

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class FrutasViewModel(
    private val frutasServices: Services,
):ViewModel() {

    private val _frutasData: MutableStateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf(ShoppingCart()))
    val frutasData: StateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>>
    get() = _frutasData

    private val _frutaData: MutableStateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf(ShoppingCart()))
    val frutaData: StateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>>
        get() = _frutaData

    private val _saladasData: MutableStateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf(ShoppingCart()))
    val saladasData: StateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>>
        get() = _saladasData

    private val _temperosData: MutableStateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf(ShoppingCart()))
    val temperosData: StateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>>
        get() = _temperosData

    lateinit var tipo:String


    fun getFrutas(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                when(tipo){
                    "fruta"->{
                        val fruta = frutasServices.getFrutas1()
                        _frutaData.value = fruta
                    }
                    "frutas"->{
                        val frutas = frutasServices.getFruta()
                        _frutasData.value = frutas
                    }
                    "saladas"->{
                        val saladas = frutasServices.getSaladas()
                        _saladasData.value = saladas
                    }
                    "temperos"->{
                        val temperos = frutasServices.getTemperos()
                        _temperosData.value = temperos
                    }

                }

            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.d("Service error",e.toString())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.example.quitanda.models

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET


interface Services {
    @GET("category/")
    suspend fun  getFruta(): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/7")
    suspend fun  getFrutas1(): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/8")
    suspend fun  getSaladas(): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/9")
    suspend fun  getTemperos(): List<ShoppingCart>
}

val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://192.168.2.157:4000/")
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

val frutasServices: Services = retrofit.create(Services::class.java)
```

My Activity:

```
package com.example.quitanda

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ShoppingCart
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.res.colorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.*
import com.example.quitanda.classes.EntryAbstract
import com.example.quitanda.classes.Helpers
import com.example.quitanda.models.FrutasViewModel
import com.example.quitanda.models.ShoppingCart
import com.example.quitanda.models.frutasServices
import com.google.accompanist.pager.ExperimentalPagerApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@ExperimentalPagerApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val entryAbstract = EntryAbstract()
    private var counter = mutableStateOf(0)
    private var ids = mutableStateListOf<ShoppingCart>()
    private lateinit var listFrutas:ArrayList<ShoppingCart>
    private lateinit var listSaladas:ArrayList<ShoppingCart>
    private lateinit var listChas:ArrayList<ShoppingCart>
    private val helpers = Helpers()


    private val viewModel by viewModels<FrutasViewModel> {
        object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return FrutasViewModel(frutasServices) as T
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{

            if(intent.hasExtra("produtos")) {
                ids = remember { intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<ShoppingCart>("produtos")!!
                    .toMutableStateList()}

                if (ids.isNotEmpty()) {

                    val aray = ids.count()
                    counter.value = aray
                }
            }

            viewModel.tipo="frutas"
            viewModel.getFrutas()
            val l by viewModel.frutasData.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())

            if (l.isEmpty()) {
                helpers.loadingComponent()
            } else {
                val i = l.filter { it.category_id==7 }
                val o = l.filter { it.category_id==8 }
                val p = l.filter { it.category_id==9 }

                listFrutas = ArrayList(i)
                listSaladas = ArrayList(o)
                listChas = ArrayList(p)
                entryAbstract.cart =ids
                entryAbstract.ccounter =counter
                entryAbstract.frutas = viewModel

                MainContent()
            }

        }
    }
```

ShoppingCart:

```
package com.example.quitanda.models

import android.os.Parcelable
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class ShoppingCart(
    var count:Int=0,
    @field:Json(name="product_title")
    var product_title:String="",
    @field:Json(name="product_id")
    var product_id:Int=0,
    @field:Json(name="photo_photo")
    var photo_photo:String="",
    @field:Json(name="product_quant")
    var product_quant:Int=0,
    @field:Json(name="category_name")
    var category_name:String="",
    @field:Json(name="category_id")
    var category_id:Int=0,
    @field:Json(name="product_description")
    var product_description:String="",
    @field:Json(name="product_price_un")
    var product_price_un:String?="",
    @field:Json(name="product_price_kg")
    var product_price_kg:String?="",
    var tipos:String=""): Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand seeing my MyViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _isRefreshing = MutableStateFlow(false)

    val isRefreshing: StateFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _isRefreshing.asStateFlow()

    fun refresh() {
        // This doesn't handle multiple 'refreshing' tasks, don't use this
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // A fake 2 second 'refresh'
            _isRefreshing.emit(true)
            delay(2000)
            _isRefreshing.emit(false)
        }
    }
}
```

how I make a viewmodel with multiple returns is a little different